# How do i toggle ng-show.. Change Html and data display when button toggles

Tags: html, angularjs, dom

I want to toggle the html+data i will display between users and posts.. It's kinda like how instagram posts/users function

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div class="button-bar">
      <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('posts')}" ng-click="setActive('posts')">Posts</a>
      <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('users')}" ng-click="setActive('users')">User</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="users">
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in users" href="#/tab/user/{{user.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{user.face}}">
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="posts">
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="post in posts" href="#/tab/post/{{post.id}}">
        <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.description}}</p>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic

Breaking down into points

- ng-init to initiale `initialtoggle` set initial value
- now on `ng-click` check change the value of `initialtoggle`.
- .. ng-class compares `initialtoggle` with `user` or `posts` value to
  apply appropriate class.
- show the appropriate div with `ng-if` comapiring value of
  `initialtoggle`.

  ```
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="initialtoggle='user'">
       <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button" 
   ng-class="{'button-positive': initialtoggle == 'posts'}"  
   ng-click="initialtoggle='posts'">Posts</a>

   <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': initialtoggle == 'user'}" 
  ng-click="initialtoggle='user'">User</a>
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="users" ng-if="initialtoggle=='user'">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="user in users" href="#/tab/user/{{user.id}}">
          <img ng-src="{{user.face}}">
          <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
         </li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="posts" ng-if="initialtoggle=='user'">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="post in posts" href="#/tab/post/{{post.id}}">
          <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
           <p>{{post.description}}</p>
         </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  ```